# Do I have to use this formula to calculate the integral?

Tags: integration

I have the following exericse:
"Calculate the integral $$\oint_C{(x+y)}ds$$ where $C$ is the line segment $x=t, y=1-t, z=0$, from $(0,1,0)$ to $(1,0,0)$."
$$$$
To calculate this integral do I have to use the following formula?
$$\oint_C{f}ds=\int_a^b{f(x(t),y(t),z(t)) \sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2+(z'(t))^2}}dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $ds = \sqrt{2}\, dt$.  Do this and it's not hard.

Comment: How did you find this equality?

Comment: You have $x'(t)=1,y'(t)=-1,z'(t)=0$

Comment: So we get to that by using the formula of my first post, don't we?

Comment: $$\oint_C{(x+y)}ds=\int_0^1{(t+1-t) \sqrt{1+1+0}}dt=\int_0^1{\sqrt{2}}dt=\sqrt{2}$$
Is that the solution?

Comment: @RossMillikan ncmathsadist Or should I improve something??

Comment: @RossMillikan So is my way to solve this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ok! Thanks a lot!